# Django Crispy Form & <select> tag

Tags: html, django, django-crispy-forms

Is it possible to use crispy-form for < select > tags?
"**|as_crispy_field**" doesn't help here

template

```
<select id="food" name="food">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
{% for object in form.fields.food.choices %}
<option value="{{ object.0 }}" class="{{ object.1 }}">{{ object.2 }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

edit: added Form.py

```py
class MealForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MealForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['food'].choices = [(food.id, food.food_number, food) for food in Food.objects.all()]
        self.fields['drink'].choices = [(drink.id, drink.pid, drink.doi, drink.type) for drink in Drink.objects.all()]



    class Meta:

        fields = (
            'title',
            'description',
            'food',
            'drink',

        )
        model = Meal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can render individual fields with crispy forms with the `crispy_field` tag

```
{% crispy_field form.food %}
```

or the `as_crispy_field` filter

```
{{ form.food|as_crispy_field }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass id and values than you can do like this

```
FOOD_OPTIONS = [(food.id, food) for food in Food.objects.all()]

class MealForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model=Meal
   food = forms.ChoiceField(choices = FOOD_OPTIONS,  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))) # here you can specify class to your select tag or remove it
```

and instead of looping in template just do like this

```
{{ form.food|as_crispy_field }}
```

Comment: as mentioned above 'as_crispy_field' does not work in the loop. 'Exception Value: 
|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field'

Comment: provide your `forms.py`

Comment: Hello @PurpleHeartOfGold check I've edited my answer